# DependencyPropertyChanged callback event is not getting fired

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a `UserControl` named `MultiChartControl`, which has a dependency property named `MultiChartInputDetails`.

```
 public ChartsData MultiChartInputDetails
    {
        get { return (ChartsData)GetValue(MultiChartInputDetailsProperty); }
        set { SetValue(MultiChartInputDetailsProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty MultiChartInputDetailsProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("MultiChartInputDetails", typeof(ChartsData), typeof(MultiChartControl), new UIPropertyMetadata(new PropertyChangedCallback(MultiChartInputDetailsChanged)));
```

But the following callback method is not getting fired even once:

```
private static void MultiChartInputDetailsChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        MultiChartControl chart = d as MultiChartControl;
        if (chart != null)
        {
            if (chart.ChartGrid.Children != null)
                chart.ChartGrid.Children.Clear();                
            chart.InitilizeData();
        }

        MessageBox.Show("MultiChartInputDetailsChanged fired");
    }
```

And the Main master control:

```
<multicharting:MultiChartControl x:Uid="multicharting:MultiChartControl_1" 
                                             MultiChartInputDetails="{Binding Path=MultiChartsInputDetails, ElementName=Chart, Converter={StaticResource DebugConverter}}"/>
```

Comment: Does the binding produce a valid value?

Answer (score 1):

This is because the DependencyProperty is not set to bind by two-way. This is done as follows:

```
DependencyProperty.Register("MultiChartInputDetails",
    typeof(ChartsData),
    typeof(MultiChartControl),
    new FrameworkPropertyMetadat(default(ChartsData), 
        FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault, 
        MultiChartInputDetailsChanged)
```

Furthermore check whether there are any binding errors. If you do not want to provide a dependency property that performs a two-way binding per default then you could write your bindinga as follows:

```
<multicharting:MultiChartControl x:Uid="multicharting:MultiChartControl_1" 
    MultiChartInputDetails="{Binding Path=MultiChartsInputDetails, 
                                     Mode=TwoWay,
                                     ElementName=Chart,
                                     Converter={StaticResource DebugConverter}}"/>
```

Comment: There is no two-way binding required to trigger the PropertyChangedCallback of a dependency property.

Comment: @Clemens no, that is not, but the value of DP will not be set if the bound variable has changed and there is no TwoWayBinding.

Comment: That is not true. You can't know anything about the source property of the binding (which unfortunately is also named MultiChartsInputDetails), because OP hasn't told us. However, if it changes and raises a change notification, the target MultiChartsInputDetails property will of course change, even in a one-way binding.